# How detect does site have an app in appstore in browser?

Tags: mobile, app-store

Sometimes iOS offer install app if site have it in appstore.
How does it work?

For example: http://habrastorage.org/files/e3f/4b2/f3b/e3f4b2f3bd6b41609ff52652acca547d.PNG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats just either an safari, figuring out that that website has an app or the website detecting your on ios and requesting a app store link or notifying safari that there is an app

Comment: Thank you.
I tried search my question(query) in G and find answer first link.

Comment: No probs, But the more ya know i suppose